# Playframework JSR-303 validated "field" does not have a corresponding accessor for data binding

Tags: java, web-applications, playframework

When I have added this following code to my project

```
Form<User> filledForm2 = userSignupForm.bindFromRequest();
```

It has stopped working by showing an error message which states:

```
Execution exception
[IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'Password' does not have a corresponding accessor for data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)]
```

My `User` class was like that:

```
class User{
String username;
String Password;
}
```

Now how can to check/modify DataBinder's configuration in java play framework?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Actually this shouldn't be happening, as Play automatically generates getters and setters, [see Guillaume's comment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/6EpJs7evg50/jGh3EuV4GgIJ).

Therefore it's possible that your IDE is causing issues e.g. Guillaume's comment re Eclipse. Or that your sbt cache is corrupt and needs cleaning, which you can do with `play clean-all` ([read about it here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/PlayConsole))

*By the way*, changing your `Password` attribute to `password` may have caused the cache to be re-generated and therefore fixed the issue.

*Update:*

For more recent versions of Play that use `activator`, it seems the following are the the up-to-date equivalents:

`activator clean` and `activator clean-files`

Comment: This is what's happening -- found it to also be a problem under 2.1.3. Just ran play clean and corrected the problem.

Comment: Same problem in 2.2.1.

Comment: `play clean-all` was the solution, thanks. (play-2.2.2)

Comment: Another issue which i spent hours figuring out is that the fields that are being populated by the form need to be public.

Comment: `activator clean` and `activator clean-files` works on play 2.4.6

Comment: activator clean and activator clean-files works on play 2.5 as well

Comment: I had the same issue with running play-2.6 (2.6.15, 2.6.17) from IDE (IntelliJ 2018.1 Community edition) as well. The solution is very similar. I've run from command line in the project folder the following commands: `sbt` , then `clean` and `run`

Answer (score 2):

My environment is Mac OS X 10.9.5 and run CentOS 7 with Vagrant. On CentOS the same problem happended, but on Mac OS didn't. Play Framework version is 2.3.8.

The commnad below didn't work in my case:

```
  activator clean
  activator clean-files
```

Though it's so weird, I had to define getter and setter to work Play Framework on CentOS7 successfully as following:

```
@Entity
public class Message extends Model{

    @Id
    public long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;


    //Add getter and setter to work successfully...
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue by using `activator clean && activator clean-files` before doing `activator dist`

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error trying to validate `int` field in POJO using 
`@Min(value = 0)`.

Solved by putting the annotation on getter in combination with `@Valid` in my bean.

Answer (score -5):

Had the same issue...

To remove this error, you should define your variables as public.

```
class User{
   public String username;
   public String password;
}
```

Comment: I have them as public and the problem is there.