# How to clean SBT cache in Play 2.4.6 using Windows Command Line?

Tags: java, web-applications, intellij-idea, sbt, playframework-2.4

I have the same problem like here: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860046/playframework-jsr-303-validated-field-does-not-have-a-corresponding-accessor-f#comment53424634_17784109)

Execution exception:

> [IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'phone' does not have a corresponding accessor for data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)]

[JSR-303](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx656.jpg)

```
@Entity
public class Contact extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String name;

    @Required
    public String phone;

    @Required
    @Email
    public String email;


    public static Finder<Long, Contact> find = new Finder<>(Contact.class);
}
```

When I add getters/setters ... it's OK

Comment: Did you try "play clean -all" command? Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860046/playframework-jsr-303-validated-field-does-not-have-a-corresponding-accessor-f

Comment: @Oldskultxo I don't know how to use Play 2 in Windows console

Comment: so you problem is bigger...   https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/PlayConsole