# How to clean cache in Java Play 2.6.x?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm getting the following error:

> [IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'ean' does not have
>   a corresponding accessor for data binding - check your DataBinder's
>   configuration (bean property versus direct field access)]

I can't find it anywhere!

Reference to this post that was using the older version of the Java Play: [Playframework JSR-303 validated "field" does not have a corresponding accessor for data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860046/playframework-jsr-303-validated-field-does-not-have-a-corresponding-accessor-f)

Comment: Did you try simply running the `sbt clean` command?

Comment: @Zenoo yes I've tried just using `clean` command within `sbt`, doesn't seem like it's doing the work

Comment: And if you try `sbt compile`, without running it, do you get the same error?

Comment: Have yout tried: `sbt clean clean-files`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483230

Comment: Not really sure why, I'm unable to execute `sbt clean clean-files`, here's what I'm getting: https://gist.github.com/glaksmono/4d954f2740f57693ba76172273a0ece3 @jschnasse

Comment: actually you can use this command `sbt clean cleanFiles`, but I'm still getting the same error on the `DataBinder` :( @jschnasse @Zenoo

Comment: Is PlayEnhancer configured? Have you configured it in `project/plugins.sbt` and `build.sbt`? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/PlayEnhancer